# Video not Autoplaying in Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have a video which is not autoplaying:

```
  <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" className="myVideo" id="vidAd">
        <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src={video} type="video/ogg"/>
        <source src={video} type="video/webm"/>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Currently the video shows up but does not autoplay.

I tried to tackle this with javascript but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var vid = document.getElementById("vidAd");
   vid.autoplay = true;
   vid.load();
});
</script>
```

Comment: On which browser ?

Comment: @Kaiido on Google Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Your code is correct only. It should work. check your browser version and supporting nature.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

HTML

```
<video preload="auto" loop="loop" muted="muted" className="myVideo" id="vidAd">
    <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/webm"/>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JS

```
var vid = document.getElementById("vidAd");
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.load();
```

Comment: I updated my question to use your answer  for javascript but I'm getting a syntax error I don't think my syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? The autoplay attribute doesn't work for browser below IE9 I believe.

Also you don't need to provide a value to the attribute 'autoplay'

```
<video preload="auto" className="myVideo" id="vidAd" loop muted autoplay>
    <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/webm"/>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Have you tried removing all the attributes on the video element except the autoplay? Maybe there's an error in one of these attributes (Loop and muted also don't require a 'value').

Comment: IE < 9 didn't support the video tag at all, so your belief that they didn't support the `autoplay` attribute must be true ;-)

Comment: Good point! it's still early morning where I am... still half asleep.... zz

Comment: @liamta thanks! I tried that but it still doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's because the video isn't automatically loaded to the screen (I have a slideshow that loads 1 video at a time)

Comment: Hmmm. How big is the video? Is it requiring a lot of buffer time? I'd suggest trying it with a placeholder MP4 to test this.

This codepen shows the video autoplaying

http://codepen.io/liamannis/pen/PpXGad

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and I just got it working. Try this.

HTML

```
<video preload="auto" className="myVideo" id="vidAd" loop muted>
    <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/webm"/>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JS

```
var vid = document.getElementById('vidAd');

vid.onloadeddata = function(event) {
  event.target.play();
}

vid.onloadeddata();
```

This will fire off the event listener onloadeddata which will occur once the video is loaded. It will then fire off the the videos play event.